# Array of FormGroup Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, formgroups

Im trying to create an array of FormGroup inside a Formgroup and I cant seem to make it work

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.surveyForm = new FormGroup({
      'surveyTitle': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'surveyDescription': new FormControl(null),
      'questionsDetail': new FormGroup(
        {
          'questionType' : new FormControl('mcq'),
          'question': new FormControl(null),
          'choices': new FormArray([])
        }),

    });
```

Im hoping to make the questionsDetail an array so i can have multiple questionsDetail in 1 survey.

My Question is How do i initialize my questionsDetails to be an array of FromGroup so that everytime i press a next button, it will push the current values to my questionDetails?

So that everytime I submit the form, its in this model

```
surveyForm = {
surveyTitle: string,
surveyDescription: string,
questionsDetails: [{
         questionType: string
         question: string
         choices: string[]
                  }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using FormBuilder for this. Here's one example of how you'd create an array with FormBuilder:

```
formExample: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.formExample = this.formBuilder.group({
            item1: new FormControl(),
            item2: new FormControl(),
            itemArray: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    arrayItem1: new FormControl(),
                    arrayItem2: new FormControl()
              })])
        });
}
```